# How to display big list of items horizontally

Tags: html, css

Folks,

I have got a new requirement to display a big list of items..say..

```
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
.
.
<li>forty</li>
</ul>
```

This has to be displayed like
either

```
one      Four
two      Five
three    Six...........Forty
```

Or

```
one      two      three....
...
... Forty
```

I am new to this html/css. inline and some other fixes were not working. Please help with some jsfiddle working example.

**Note**: Only 3/4 items need to displayed in one column and max of 6 to 8 columns should be displayed like shown below.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: can you show example of it??. I am not getting it.

Comment: the output is not clear to me:  do you need to display 40 items in a table-like structure with 3 rows or 3 columns, right?

Comment: added example..please find it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**CSS Columns**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) would be one option here:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-column-count: 8;
  -moz-column-count: 8;
  column-count: 8;
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  column-gap: px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
  <li>List Item 6</li>
  <li>List Item 7</li>
  <li>List Item 8</li>
  <li>List Item 9</li>
  <li>List Item 10</li>
  <li>List Item 11</li>
  <li>List Item 12</li>
  <li>List Item 13</li>
  <li>List Item 14</li>
  <li>List Item 15</li>
  <li>List Item 16</li>
  <li>List Item 17</li>
  <li>List Item 18</li>
  <li>List Item 19</li>
  <li>List Item 20</li>
  <li>List Item 21</li>
  <li>List Item 22</li>
  <li>List Item 23</li>
  <li>List Item 24</li>
  <li>List Item 25</li>
  <li>List Item 26</li>
  <li>List Item 27</li>
  <li>List Item 28</li>
  <li>List Item 29</li>
  <li>List Item 30</li>
  <li>List Item 31</li>
  <li>List Item 32</li>
  <li>List Item 33</li>
  <li>List Item 34</li>
  <li>List Item 35</li>
  <li>List Item 36</li>
  <li>List Item 37</li>
  <li>List Item 38</li>
  <li>List Item 39</li>
  <li>List Item 40</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Paulie_D, sorry for delay..your code is working fine for me..but i would like to restrict 6 articles for 1 column as shown above..how can i achieve this..thanks for your code :)

Comment: You have to make a choice between how many columns you want and the height of the list. If you set the height of the columns to the height of 6 list items you don't need the `column-count` property.

Comment: Yes paulie_D i agree with you..but Article name differs everytime with very big name which lead to 2 line display and i want to restrict only 6 articles instead of height which doesnt help me when i have a big length words..kindly suggest some idea..

Comment: Then this solution is not for you. There is no method to set the number of list items per column if the height of the list items is not known....in fact there is no CSS method to do this with **any** layout. You would need javascript to do that.

Comment: Ok then i will try with javascript paulie..thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

Check this below fiddle

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xedkxfzL/3/)**

**CSS:**

```
ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 0;
  margin:5px 2%;
  background-color:red;
  width:20%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: this is also working fine..precisely below one helps with column count as well..thanks for your help arun :)

Comment: this is perfect , just my list were need to be tighter I just use 1px margin and `padding : 1px 0 ; `